# Elixir: GenStage topology

Tags: elixir, genstage

For self-educational purposes I try to learn Elixir and to wrap my head around `GenStage` library.

I read the documentation and got it for the most part, however I have a couple of questions for my particular domain.

I try to build a web-scraper, which should start several times per day and do some scraping and post-processing.

## First question

So, my topmost producer is a `Stage` that makes HTTP requests and hands them down to consumers.

How do I handle "wait 6 hours" here?

Should I just accept demands, but send empty events to consumers? That sounds like a waste of CPU cycles.

Maybe, `GenStage` is not a right approach for this kind of events?

## Second question

Sometimes I need to return an event back to the chain.

- `ProducerConsumerA` loads page #n
- `ProducerConsumerB` parses page and emits events for items found on the page to the next Consumers. But it also should send an event for `ProducerConsumerA` for the next page (if the results are paginated)

Comment: If you are going to wait 6 hours - that is 6 hours of Erlang VM running on your computer -a cron job that launches an your elixir program may be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that GenStage may be a little overkill for what your trying to do. Especially if your only scraping every 6 hours. Furthermore, if your just learning Elixir, you may what to start with a more basic approach. You can always refactor later if you feel you need more flow control.

I would create one main GenServer that does the scraping serially. You can start it with the list of sites to scrape, and have it work though the list. Once a site have been fetched, you could start a `Task` to process the data and then fetch the next site, starting a new processing `Task` each time.

When your done scrapping all the sites, you can use `Process.send_after` to send a wakeup message that will start the next cycle of scraping.

This will give you a good understanding of Elixir and OTP. Once you have this all working, you can then investigate GenStage further.